# Invalid or unexpected token in Kantu if condition

Tags: selenium, ui-automation, kantu

I'm using the [Kantu web automation tool](https://a9t9.com/) for the first time. Most of it is intuitive, but I'm now encountering an error when looping through a CSV. The relevant part of my script is:

```
{
  "Command": "echo",
  "Target": "Found customer with email ${emailAddress}",
  "Value": ""
},
{
  "Command": "echo",
  "Target": "Expected email name: ${!COL1}",
  "Value": ""
},
{
  "Command": "if",
  "Target": "${emailAddress} == \"${!COL1}@domain.com\"",
  "Value": ""
},
```

This produces the following log:

> [info] Executing:  | echo | Found customer with email ${emailAddress} |  |
>
> [echo] Found customer with email 70866223@domain.com
>
> [info] Executing:  | echo | Expected email name: ${!COL1} |  |
>
> [echo] Expected email name: 70866223
>
> [info] Executing:  | if | ${emailAddress} == "${!COL1}@domain.com" |  |
>
> [error] Error in runEval condition of if: Invalid or unexpected token

So you can see the variables `${emailAddress}` and `${!COL1}` are stored correctly, but my `if` condition is not evaluating correctly. I've also tried changing `\"${!COL1}@domain.com\"` to `${!COL1} + \"@domain.com\"` with same result.

I assume this is something to do with escape characters or something, but I can't find anything related in the docs. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The if expression](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/selenium-ide/if) is handled like in storeEval. To quote from one of the storeEval examples in the [docs](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/selenium-ide/storeeval) :

> x="${myvar}"; x.length;
>
> Note that our variable ${myvar} is converted to a text string before the Javascript EVAL is executed. Therefore ${myvar} has to be inside "..." like any other text.

So I'd say the reason your code fails on the if is that your ${emailAddress} is not inside a String.

```
"${emailAddress}" == "${!COL1}@domain.com"
```

should work.

Comment: Hey @PinkiePie, what is your gripe with my edits to this reply? The syntax I gave was 100% correct - so why did you decline it?

Comment: @getsetcode - {
  "Command": "if",
  "Target": "\"${emailAddress}\" == \"${!COL1}@domain.com\"",
  "Value": ""
} ... this is the correct code to your problem.

Comment: Hey @SilSur, your suggested edit was peer reviewed. You can check out the status and the reasons for rejection here https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23034100  Hope that helps :)